# How to merge return values of multiple functions?

Tags: php, arrays, merge

How could I merge the return value of multiple functions?

I'm placing my option arrays within functions so I can call those functions (arrays) more easily because they will be needed more than once in different locations.

I would like to run my different arrays options each in their own function.

The reason for this is so I can allow devs to choose which of the arrays of those functions they want to use when extending but at the same time keep the function simple, rather than putting all my array values in one lengthy function.

So I just wondered is there a way like `array_merge` for functions where I could merge the returned values of multiple functions?

Here is an example of what I am doing...

```
function One() {

    $var = array(1,2);

    return $var;

}

function Two() {

    $var = array(3,4);

    return $var;

}

// Like array merge I would like to merge the returned values of the functions
// Like $var = function_merge('One', 'Two');
```

So the value you would be just like `array_merge()`;

Example: $var = array(1,2,3,4);

Comment: You just can send the response of one function to the other function & merge within the function. Or, you can save the results of each function in its own variable then at the end merge all the variables

Comment: `$var = array_merge(One(), Two());`

Comment: Yep. Just thought of option #2 and posted it. And @manian Do you have an example of method #1? I'm not sure what you mean or if I have ever done something like that but I would like to look at that method and see which I like best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call the functions that return an array in the **array_merge()** method itself. Like this:

```
$var = array_merge(One(), Two());
```

or, to address the concern @manian brought up, use this:

```
$var = array_merge(array_values(One()), array_values(Two()));
// array_values() removes and resets an array's indexes
```

This will return

```
    Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
)
```

Comment: Oh!!! So you can merge the function by name itself within array_merge(). Hmm... didn't know that. That is essentially what I was thinking. Thanks about the numeric input. I'll play with it for a moment. Appreciate it.

Comment: It will work. I meant to say that if the same index found in both arrays, then it will replace the older one with new one. We only have one value

Comment: Ok, yes. I see that. I just got done playing with it. All seems to work well. Appreciate it!

Comment: @NoahjChampion If my solution works for you, please consider selecting my answer as correct. Thanks

Comment: @SterlingBeason I am :D Too bad there is not an option to select multiple answers when they apply, as the do now. So I'm going to go by the simplest or the method I personally find as my answer, ie: the method I will actually use. So playing with the functions now to test. That's why I didn't mark my answer as correct because someone might have a better method to use. - Thanks for the update on the array_values();

Comment: @NoahjChampion Hard to beat my one liner! Let me know when you choose : )

Comment: @SterlingBeason yep, done. This one is the best for me but also I think best for devs. It's running what we're used to or doesn't take much to learn, just running the functions in the array_merge(); :D Every thing works fine for me. Thanks! Appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... maybe there are some other ideas?

I was overthinking this I think. Just thought of storing each function in a $var then merging those $vars

Like...

```
$var_1 = One();
$var_2 = Two();

$output = array_merge($var_1, $var_2);

print_r($output);
```

// Returns

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
)
```

Answer (score 0):

for static usage

```
function function_merge($fnc1, $fnc2) {
    return array_merge($fnc1(), $fnc2());
}
//use => function_merge('one', 'two');
```

for dynamic usage

```
function function_merge() {
    $arguments = func_get_args();
    $result = [];
    if (is_array($arguments) && (count($arguments) > 0)) {
        foreach ($arguments as $fnc) {
            if (function_exists($fnc)) {
                $result = array_merge($result, $fnc());
            }
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
//use => function_merge('one', 'two', 'three', 'four');
//use => function_merge('vegas', 'newyork', 'ohio');
```

Comment: Hmmm... I think I like this method. I'll play with it for a moment. I think I might like it better. Do you have any comments on performance of my method below vs. the func_get_args() method? Would it be slower?

Comment: you can check how long it takes to call by using microtime() before and after the call, but i don't think you'll face any performance problem

Answer (score 0):

Here is the method that you asked for,

```
$merged = array();
function One($merged) {
  $var = array(1,2);
  return array_merge($merged, $var);
}

function Two($merged) {
  $var = array(3,4);
  return array_merge($merged, $var);
}
$merged = One($merged);
$merged = Two($merged);

print_r($merged);
```